# Trying to write a recursive program that reveals all adjacent tiles that are blank

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm trying to make a clone of minesweeper. In that game, there is a feature that, whenever you click an empty box, all adjacent empty tiles are revealed and empty tiles adjacent to those empty tiles are also revealed.

Right now when I tried to implement this, it only reveals the 8 adjacent tiles of the tile I clicked, not any other empty tiles which are next to the empty tiles revealed

Here is the code that I'm running right now (it has 2 parameters row and col):

```
local rowCords = {row-16, row, row+16}
local colCords = {col-16, col, col+16}

--Check surroundings 
for r = 1, 3, 1 do
    for c = 1, 3, 1 do
        curRow = rowCords[r]
        curCol = colCords[c]        

        if (curRow >= 16 and curRow <= 400 and curCol >= 16 and curCol <= 176) then
            if boardCords[Board:getBox(curRow, curCol)].value == 1 then
                boardCords[Board:getBox(curRow, curCol)].revealed = true
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your algorithm you are checking only 9 tiles, but you must do this recursively for checked tiles. So your algorithm must be like:

```lua
function revealTile(row, col)
  if (row >= 16 and row <= 400 and col >= 16 and col <= 176) then
    local tile = boardCords[Board:getBox(row, col)]
    -- Try to reveal tile
    if not tile.revealed and tile.value == 1 then
      tile.revealed = true
      -- Try to reveal surroundings
      for r = row-16,row+16,16 do
        for c = col-16,col+16,16 do
          revealTile(r, c)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your program makes a lot of sense, but when I'm trying to run your code, it only reveals one tile. Also, I tried the recursive thing in my own code as well, but in the end, I just get a stack overflow

Comment: You did not provide information how you store your data and why coordinates are step of 16. As I understood acording to your algorithm, empty tile has `value==1`. You have stack overflow as you are checking the same tile multiple times, so you must check `not tile.revealed` before checking the surrounding.

Comment: Nvm, I got it to work. Ur suggestion of not tile.revealed worked. Thank You!